# ADSL Router fix max rate

Tags: adsl, adsl-router, adsl2+

My ADSL2+ router gives me the following statistics:

SNR Margin: 14.5
Line Attenuation: 17.0
Data Rate: 4678 kbps
Max Rate: 11000 kbps

i don't know why my max rate is low i need it to be at least 12000 anyone could help me increas it

Comment: You should ask your ISP about this. You may need to pay for a higher speed

Comment: Your speed will be limited by your ISP and the wiring between your house and ISP. Unless your house is wired with wet string there isn't going to be much you can do. Contact your ISP and find out if they offer better services.

Comment: To be fair 11Mbps is reasonable for ADSL. If you need faster then you are going to have to upgrade to VDSL (otherwise known as FTTC - Fibre To The Curb) or full fibre (FTTP - Fibre To The Premises). and both of those need your ISP to be involved.

Comment: Try unplugging everything other then adsl from all the phone jacks - maybe you have a bad filter.